# Can't display different forms for different user types

Tags: python, django

I have 2 user types, teacher and student. I have built the view to be able to edit a student profile. But I also needed a different one for teacher. I didn't want 2 views, because that would be pointless. Now, for teacher it works as intended, but for some reason for teacher, the same form as for the student is displayed... a teacher has different attributes so it has a different form I need to show.

```css
class TeacherEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    academic_title = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    bio = forms.Textarea()
    website = forms.URLField(required=False)
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)

class StudentEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=False)
```

```html
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        student = Student.objects.get(user=user)
        s = True
    except ValueError:
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user=user)

    if not s:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TeacherEditForm(instance=teacher)
        else:
            form = TeacherEditForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
    elif s:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = StudentEditForm(instance=student)
        else:
            form = StudentEditForm(request.POST, instance=student)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "registration/profile_edit.html", context)
```

Comment: I believe you meant "Now, for *student* it works as intended, but for some reason for teacher [...]", right? Also, in your application, can the user be a `Student` and a `Teacher` at the same time? If so, you will need to workout the view. Because if the user is associated with a `Student` and with a `Teacher` instance at the same time, this view will always display the `StudentEditForm`.

Comment: Yes Mr. Freitas you are right. Btw, im the student that wrote you about another issue before. A student cannot be a teacher. Here are my models, if you could tell me what to do: https://pastebin.com/dh3n5yPR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason for your code be always using the `StudentEditForm` is because the `request.user` is always associated with a `Student` instance.

Considering a scenario where the user is a `Teacher` and has no relationship with the `Student` model, your code would raise an exception. As abahnihi mentioned, you should catch a `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception instead of `ValueError`:

```
try:
    student = Student.objects.get(user=user)
    s = True
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user=user)
```

The best way to achieve the desired behaviour is writing unit testing.

In any case, just to make sure that's the problem, do a quick "debug" using `print` statements on top of your view:

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    print(request.user.student_id)
    print(request.user.teacher_id)

    #... rest of your view
```

If you get two IDs on the console, that means your user is a `Teacher` and a `Student`.

If this is not an intended behaviour you have to make sure your application won't let it happen. Otherwise, you will need two separate views (or at least two URLs), one to edit the `Student` profile and the other to edit the `Teacher` profile.

In any case, here is how you can improve your view:

```
from django.db import transaction

@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user

    if hasattr(user, 'student') and isinstance(user.student, Student):
        form_class = StudentEditForm
        profile_model = user.student  # reverse relationship via OneToOne link
    else:
        form_class = TeacherEditForm
        profile_model = user.teacher

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST, instance=profile_model)
        if form.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():  # two database operations, wrap in a transaction for consistency
                profile_model = form.save()
                user.email = profile_model.email
                user.save()
                return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=profile_model)

    return render(request, 'registration/profile_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

The code above is considering the following assumptions:

- The `Student` and `Teacher` models are as described in your [pastebin url](https://pastebin.com/dh3n5yPR);
- The user will either be a `Student` or a `Teacher`, but never both at the same time.

Comment: Anyway, I came to answer in the end by doing the following. By taking example of your application on github (Django School) I added is_teacher and is_student when people create their accounts. This way I was able to differentiate between user types. Thank you for your implication.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason is, you need to assign a default False value to variable s at the beginning:

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    s = False
    user = request.user
```

But in all case, you need to make sure the consistency of the database. I mean you may have a user (request.user) in both student and teacher; be careful.

Comment: Check my models in the previous comment please.. maybe that will help figuring out my issues. This won't solve it.

Comment: You also need to catch another error in the except condition. You may need to use except ObjectDoesNotExist or leave the except without defining an exception